# Activity process does not terminate?

Tags: activity-monitor, macvim

[image]I am using a Mac and I use Macvim for programming. If my program happens to go into an infinite loop and I have to quit Macvim and restart it due to this the program will restart but the program process keeps running. I realized this when I opened up my activity monitor and see "program foo" is still running at about 99% cpu usage! I can easily shut down the process from activity monitor but is there a way to prevent this? Thanks in advance for any suggestions. Test is the file the loop went into. I created it to show an example.

Comment: The process from the program you were working is not quitting properly? or A macvim process is not quitting properly? More specifics? If its the program you're writing, fix your code maybe, so as to not cause an infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks. I am not worried about the loop, I understand fixing an infinite loop. My issue is the process for the program continues to show in activity monitor even after i quite Macvim due to an infinite loop.

Comment: But when you say "the program", is "the program" MacVim or the program you are writing?

Comment: If the program i am coding goes into an infinite loop due to an error i must quit Macvim. Even after i quit Macvim the program that went into the loop still shows up in Acitvity monitor and is taking up 99% CPU. I know the easy fix is to not cause an infinite loop but they happen. I can shut the program process down via Activity monitor but i wish the process would terminate once i quit Macvim. Making sense?

Comment: When i say "the program" it is the program i am writing, obviously in Macvim. BUT activity monitor will only show the file name and not Macvim. Example Activity monitor would say "foo.cpp" 99% CPU.

Comment: I added a screen shot to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MacVim forks (spawns a new process) to launch external processes, but it waits for the external process to return before resuming execution. Thus, killing MacVim simply detaches the child process (your program) from MacVim and attaches it to the main process running, in essence, OS X on the whole.

You have to quit, or Force Quit, your program explicitly in order to kill it.

It's also very likely that if you kill your program, and NOT MacVim, you can continue using MacVim without issue.

Comment: Would you happen to know which command would kill the program without quitting Macvim? I can only find documentation on saving and quitting etc.?

Comment: If pressing `control c` doesn't work, you can select and kill your app via Activity Monitor first, and then MacVim should start working again.

Comment: From the Terminal `ps auxr | grep test | head -1 | awk {'print$2'} | xargs -t kill -9` where _test_ is the name of your application. No need for Activity Monitor.

Comment: @afragen I'll do you one better: `killall -s KILL test`, where test is the name of your application.

Comment: @JasonSalaz unless you have other processes with that name...

Comment: JasonSalaz touché @Daniel the same can be said for my solution.